# How can I override the VoiceOver cursor rectangle for a custom UIButton?

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover

I have a UIViewController which contains two UIViews in a splitter-type interface. On the first view I have a number of UIButtons which are normally positioned such that the buttons extend off the edge of the view, and are thus not fully visible. The problem with the VoiceOver cursor in this case is that the cursor surrounds the full extent of the button, and thus the cursor extends out to the right of the view.

In a training class for accessibility, I was told that you can somehow override the default cursor around the edge of the button and have it instead surround whatever rectangle you like, but I can't find how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to set a custom [accessibilityFrame](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAccessibility_Protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSObject/accessibilityFrame) on each button.  You can get the part of each button's frame that is on screen if you intersect the screen rect with each button's frame using [CGRectIntersection()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectIntersection).

Answer (score 1):

You can [adapt the focus area](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#modify-the-focus-area-of-voiceover) of every accessible element you want using the `accessibilityFrame` or the `accessibilityPath` if you must draw something else than a rectangle.
The `union` method may be very helpful in the first case to construct your final rectangle.

At the end, don't forget to specify the `accessibilityActivationPoint` so as not to have an unpleasant surprise using the different sizes of the `Dynamic Type`.